# Is there a naming rule to define when the 's' is appended to the function name?

Tags: c#

As a good example to illustrate this question. let us see how the System.Object contains:

```
Equals                => with 's'
GetHashCode
GetType
ReferenceEquals       => with 's'  
ToString
Finalize
MemberwiseClone
```

So, is there a general rule in the best practice that we can follow for when we should append a 's' in the end of the function name?

// updated //

Why not use **Finalizes** or **MemberwiseClones** instead?

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, this just follows the vagaries of the English language, which can be very difficult to master for non-native speakers.

The idea is that:

- `a.Equals(b)` should read "A equals B." "Equals" is the proper conjugation of the transitive verb "to equal" when the subject is singular (like "A").
- `a.GetHashCode()` should read "a dot GetHashCode", since you plan to "get the hash code" from the object represented by the variable `a`.
- `a.Finalize()` should read "a dot Finalize", meaning you are planning to "finalize" the object represented by the variable `a`.

Other examples of adding an "s" typically follow a singular-vs-plural rule. For example:

- `type.GetCustomAttributes()` indicates that there will be a collection of "attributes" returned, rather than just a single "attribute."

Answer (score 1):

As other people have mentioned, it's a nuance of the English language... I would say the rule of thumb is that if it's returning a `bool` then ending with an 's' is appropriate. It's almost like a shortening of DoesXXX (DoesEqual => Equals, DoesReferenceEqual => ReferenceEquals). For properties, the convention is starting the property name with IsXXX (IsEmpty, IsEnum, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find anything to reference your question, but the functions with an S at the end are used as verbs. So, if read literally -

Does Object.Equals something? or Does 1 (an object) + 1 (an object) Equals 2 (an object).

Give me the Object.GetHashCode.

Equals is more descriptive. If I were to use Equal, then I would probably change it to IsEqual but Equals is shorter, so that is used.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is one,

```
Equals(object,object);
```

is just more descriptive than

```
Equal(object,object);
```

Comment: But in this case, `AreEqual(object, object)` would make more sense to me, since you're trying to say "these two objects 'are equal'."

Comment: The problem with this answer is that this syntax shows a global `Equals` method rather than an instance method, as actually used in C#. The fact is, `myObject.Equals(otherObject)` is preferred (almost?) exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

Equals can be considered a short form of "IsEqualTo".  The main differentiator for using it is plural versus singular.  For example, GetType implies singular usage and that one type is returned.  GetTypes would imply plural usage and that multiple types would be returned (as an array, collection, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You append an 's' when the method name has an 's' in the last word in English.

Generally you want to use third-person present tense verbs and then either singular or plural nouns as needed, and you want to try to have your code read almost like English. Thus:

```
bool areEqual = myObject.Equals(otherObject);     // set boolean value areEqual if myObject Equals otherObject
bool containsSomething = myObject.HasSomething(); // set boolean value containsSomething if myObject Has Something

string myStr = myObject.ToString();               // myStr is myObject [converted] To String

int hashCode = myObject.GetHashCode();            // Take myObject, Get [its] Hash Code, and store into integer variable hashCode
```

The better you know English, the more it will begin to make sense.

---

Why not use `Finalizes()`? Because in English that would suggest that the object is doing the Finalizing, or else assert that the object does Finalize something. `Finalize()` on the other hand is more like a command you're sending to the object: "You! Object! Yes, you! ...Go finalize yourself!"

In the case of `MemberwiseClone()`, this is because only one Clone is being returned. Since Clone is a noun, that means Clones would imply more than one clone.